# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: table "live" does not exist Pushing large dataframe to postgres database

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, multithreading, multiprocessing

Am trying to push a large dataframe to the Postgres db, am using df_to_sql for this, the problem is it takes forever to complete this task, I have up to 1millions of dataframe rows, so I decided to use the python multiprocessing.

below are my codes

```
def parallelize_push_to_db(df, table, chunk_size):
    chunk = split_df(df, chunk_size=chunk_size)
    chunk_len = len(chunk)
    processes = list()
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(chunk_len):
        process = Process(target=pussh_df_to_db, args=(chunk[i], table))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
        for pro in processes:
            pro.join()
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'parra {end_time}')

def split_df(df, chunk_size):
    chunks = list()
    split_size = math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_size)
    for i in range(split_size):
        chunks.append(df[i * chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size])
    return chunks

def pussh_df_to_db(df, table):
    # i think we should append the new df to the data in the db if not empty
    base = DB_Base()
    base.pg_cur.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table}")
    print(df.shape)
    print('running...........to send dt to postgres')
    df.to_sql(table, con=base.sql_alchemy_engine_conn, if_exists='replace')

if "__name__" == "__main__":
    parallelize_push_to_db(check_data, 'live', 1000)
```

some part of the code run but fails at the later part with the below error

```
in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) table "user_user_recommendations_AAa" does not exist

[SQL: 
DROP TABLE "live"]
```

i think each process tries to create a new table and drop the old one, i really dont know how to solve this, any help??

Comment: Yes each process will attempt to drop the table. Why are you dropping the table instead of just appending the rows (if_exists="append" instead of if_exists='replace')?  I'm not sure why the error is there though, as to_sql will create the table again so you shouldn't be getting a table does not exist. .

Comment: What happens if you create that table in postgres before you run this code, remove the drop table statement, and use 'append' instead of 'replace' ?

Comment: okay will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before i start, i will like to say, you will be better off using the threading modules, before making the decisions of using this sort of techniques you must understand the task you are doing. some tasks are cpu tasks whiles others are I/O heavy task. so try and understand all this before you choose which one you want, but sometimes they both will work.

```
def parallelize_push_to_db(df, table, chunk_size):
    chunk = split_df(df, chunk_size=chunk_size)
    chunk_len = len(chunk)
    processes = list()
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(chunk_len):
        process = Process(target=pussh_df_to_db, args=(chunk[i], table))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    for pro in processes:
        pro.join()
    end_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'parra {end_time}')
```

the first Ans will also work, but a solution for your question is this..

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative ways:

1. save the df to a csv file, and copy to the postgresql db.

refer: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html

```
COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN }
    [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]

where option can be one of:

    FORMAT format_name
    OIDS [ boolean ]
    FREEZE [ boolean ]
    DELIMITER 'delimiter_character'
    NULL 'null_string'
    HEADER [ boolean ]
    QUOTE 'quote_character'
    ESCAPE 'escape_character'
    FORCE_QUOTE { ( column_name [, ...] ) | * }
    FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] )
    ENCODING 'encoding_name'
```

2. use a fast way to dump df to db.

refer: https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/16089da

```sql
import io
import csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
def df2db(df_a, table_name, engine):
    output = io.StringIO()
    # ignore the index
    # df_a.to_csv(output, sep='\t', index = False, header = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    df_a.to_csv(output, sep='\t', index = False, header = False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
    output.getvalue()
    # jump to start of stream
    output.seek(0)
    
    # engine -> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    connection = engine.raw_connection() 
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # null value become ''
    cursor.copy_from(output,table_name,null='')
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:passport@localhost:5432/databasname')
df2db(df, table_name, engine)
```